# error in dividing 2 pandas series with decimal values (daily stock price)

Tags: pandas, unsupportedoperation

I am trying to divide 2 pandas columns (same column divided by shifting one cell) but getting an error as below...

..This is surprising as I have done such computation many times before on time series data and never encountered this issue.

Can someone suggest what is going on here?...I am computing the daily returns of Adj Close price of a stock so need the answer in decimal.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert to `float` first column, because `dtype` is `object`, what is obviously `string`:

```
z = x.astype(float) / y.astype(float)
```

Or:

```
data['Adj Close'] = data['Adj Close'].astype(float)
z = data['Adj Close'].shift(-1) / data['Adj Close']
```

Comment: still gives an error..ValueError: could not convert string to float: null

Comment: Then use `data['Adj Close'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Adj Close'], errors='coerce')`